# Login With Facebook Working on Localhost (xampp) but not on real website

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api, facebook-login

I am using this tutorial to add a [Login with Facebook feature](https://www.codexworld.com/login-with-facebook-using-php/). I have tested this on my localhost and it is working perfectly fine.

But, I am getting this error on my website:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Facebook\HttpClients\FacebookCurlHttpClient' not found in /home/KC/web/example.com/public_html/facebook-php-sdk/FacebookClient.php:127 Stack trace: #0 /home/KC/web/example.com/public_html/facebook-php-sdk/FacebookClient.php(96): Facebook\FacebookClient->detectHttpClientHandler() #1 /home/KC/web/example.com/public_html/facebook-php-sdk/Facebook.php(159): Facebook\FacebookClient->__construct(NULL, false) #2 /home/KC/web/example.com/public_html/fbConfig.php(25): Facebook\Facebook->__construct(Array) #3 /home/KC/web/example.com/public_html/index.php(3): require_once('/home/KC/web/ex...') #4 {main} thrown in /home/KC/web/example.com/public_html/facebook-php-sdk/FacebookClient.php on line 127

I have no idea, what that error means. What am I missing?

Comment: yes you need to give the url of the live site in the app of facebook, previously where you give localhost and callback url

Comment: I did that @Exprator

Comment: what is your sdk version of fb?

Comment: How do i check that sir? It is working on localhost, but not on my website. That article got posted or  updated before 7 days, so probably it is the latest version.

Comment: ok providing the ans, check if you have missed anything in the file from where you are calling the fb api

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
set_include_path("your path to Facebook SDK ");

require_once('Facebook/HttpClients/FacebookHttpable.php');
require_once('Facebook/HttpClients/FacebookCurl.php');
require_once('Facebook/HttpClients/FacebookCurlHttpClient.php');
require_once('Facebook/FacebookSession.php');
require_once('Facebook/FacebookRedirectLoginHelper.php');
require_once('Facebook/FacebookRequest.php');
require_once('Facebook/FacebookResponse.php');
require_once('Facebook/FacebookSDKException.php');
require_once('Facebook/FacebookRequestException.php');
require_once('Facebook/FacebookOtherException.php');
require_once('Facebook/FacebookAuthorizationException.php');
require_once('Facebook/GraphObject.php');
require_once('Facebook/GraphSessionInfo.php');
require_once('Facebook/GraphUser.php');

use Facebook\HttpClients\FacebookHttpable;
use Facebook\HttpClients\FacebookCurl;
use Facebook\HttpClients\FacebookCurlHttpClient;
use Facebook\FacebookSession;
use Facebook\FacebookRedirectLoginHelper;
use Facebook\FacebookRequest;
use Facebook\FacebookResponse;
use Facebook\FacebookSDKException;
use Facebook\FacebookRequestException;
use Facebook\FacebookOtherException;
use Facebook\FacebookAuthorizationException;
use Facebook\GraphObject;
use Facebook\GraphSessionInfo;
use Facebook\GraphUser;
```

add this line in your code

Comment: 2 errors now `Warning: require_once(Facebook/HttpClients/FacebookHttpable.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/KC/web/example.com/public_html/fbConfig.php on line 13
`

Comment: `Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required 'Facebook/HttpClients/FacebookHttpable.php' (include_path='/facebook-php-sdk/autoload.php') in /home/KC/web/example.com/public_html/fbConfig.php on line 13
`

Comment: remove the 2 line which are  causing error and check, may be they are not needed in recent version

Comment: are you sure you are passing the correct path, because i think its a path problem

Comment: The code is after public_html. I put the code as it is, shown in codex website. I think all path is right. I checked the whole code like 8 times

Comment: https://github.com/facebook/php-graph-sdk download this and put it in your server and check

Comment: the path for autoload.php will be php-graph-sdk-5.5\src\Facebook\autoload.php

Comment: hey bro dont call me sir, i am a learner too bro, or else would have given the right ans at a moment, wouldnt have wasted so many comments, anyways glad could help bro, just call me bro, if you need any other help, take care :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149350/discussion-between-josh-poor-and-exprator).

I got few off-topic questions, if you are free :)